# Alternative form of FactorInteger? (Mathematica)

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In Mathematica

```
a = FactorInteger[44420069694]
```

assigns

```
{{2, 1}, {3, 1}, {7, 1}, {11, 2}, {13, 1}, {23, 2}, {31, 1}, {41, 1}}
```

to a. Now instead of the factors with their exponents I would like each of those lists expanded. The above factorization would then become

```
{2, 3, 7, 11, 11, 13, 23, 23, 31, 41}
```

I wrote the following function:

```
b = {}; Do[Do[b = Append[b, a[[i]][[1]]], {a[[i]][[2]]}], {i, Length[a]}]
```

but if you ask me it looks fugly. There sure must be a neater way to do achieve this?

Comment: Steven, since you started posting on Mathematica.SE I was looking at your profile to see where else you contribute and I found this old question.  I admit this is self-seeking but I feel that my answer is superior to the one you accepted.  Would you take another look at it?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - Wow, must have been my first encounter with MMA. I must have missed your answer when you posted (2 years later) but it looks better indeed: shorter looks impossible, and apparently fastest too (though that wasn't my first worry). Upvoted and accepted. (BTW, you said you noted that I was #1 on EE, but now I realize *you* are #1 on MMA! :-)). Thanks for reminding me of your answer.

Comment: Thanks :D  What's that they say about the squeaky wheel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yet another way in Mathematica 6 or later.

In:= `Flatten[ConstantArray @@@ a]`

Out=`{2, 3, 7, 11, 11, 13, 23, 23, 31, 41}`

even shorter:

`Join @@ ConstantArray @@@ a`

---

### A speed comparison of methods posted

Using the these functions (in the order they were posted):

```
zvrba = Flatten[Map[Table[#[[1]], {#[[2]]}] &, #]] &;
dreeves = Sequence @@ Table[#1, {#2}] & @@@ # &;
gdelfino = Flatten[# /. {p_, n_} :> Table[p, {n}]] &;
mrwizard = Join @@ ConstantArray @@@ # &;
sasha = Function[{p, e}, Array[p &, e, 1, Sequence]] @@@ # &;
```

and assigning them the letters Z, D, G, M, S respectively, here are Timing charts of their efficiency.

First, for increasing number of lists in the input:

[image]

Second, for increasing exponent (length of repetition) in each list:

[image]

Note that these charts are logarithmic.  Lower is better.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, for example:

```
Flatten[Map[Table[#[[1]], {#[[2]]}] &, a]]
```

Comment: Thanks, zvrba. You say "for example", that means you have other solutions like this? I'm just learning, so any code is welcome. Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

Here's another way to do it:

```
rptseq[x_, n_] := Sequence @@ Table[x, {n}]
rptseq @@@ a
```

Which can be condensed with a lambda function to:

```
Sequence @@ Table[#1, {#2}] & @@@ a
```

zvrba's answer can also be condensed a bit, if you're into that sort of thing:

```
Flatten[Table[#1, {#2}]& @@@ a]
```

(Now that I look at that, I guess my version is a very minor variant on zvrba's.)

Answer (score 4):

You could also use:

```
a /. {p_, n_} -> Table[p, {n}] // Flatten
```

**UPDATE 2017/10/18**:

My answer above fails "in the case of two distinct prime factors" as pointed out by Cory Walker. This update fixes it:

```
a /. {p_Integer, n_Integer} -> Table[p, {n}] // Flatten
```

notice that the benchmark done by Mr Wizard was done with the original version before this update.

Comment: This does not work for the case of two distinct prime factors: {{3, 5}, {5, 2}} /. {p_, n_} -> Table[p, {n}] // Flatten

Answer (score 3):

One can also use Array to process the answer. Here is a short code doing this:

```
In[11]:= PrimeFactorInteger[i_Integer] := 
 Function[{p, e}, Array[p &, e, 1, Sequence]] @@@ FactorInteger[i]

In[12]:= PrimeFactorInteger[2^3 3^2 5]

Out[12]= {2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5}
```